# Oracle Apex report fixed header needs vertical scrollbar displayed out of the region

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle Apex(version 4.1.1) interactive report.
The report uses a template which makes the headers fixed and the report region scrollable (vertical scrollbar).

The issue is that the scrollbar hides up the data in the last column.

Please provide suggestions so as to how can the scrollbar be moved out of the region.

The report is in form of a table with table rows tr, table data td and table headers th.
So please suggest what css attributes can be useful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding to make the numbers appear, like:

```
tbody td:nth-child(4n){    
   padding-right: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Luis why 4n? should i give the exact column number like 15?

Comment: Thanks @Luis , i used td:last-child
It worked. thanks a ton :)